# Authentication with Gitblit as Plug-in in Gerrit

Tags: apache, gerrit, gitblit

I have a Gerrit installation on ubuntu which uses HTTP Authentication with an apache2.
As a viewer we would like to use Gitblit as a plug-in in Gerrit.
I found already the plugin here [here](https://github.com/tomaswolf/gerrit-gitblit-plugin) and I followed the install instruction there.

Since all other plugins in Gerrit works properly, like blabla.com/gerrit/plugins/gitiles/ or some other, I always get a log-in request when I try to browse to blabla.com/gerrit/plugins/gitblit/ (Also the documentation folder).

I think I have anything wrong or missing in the apache2 configuration, but I don't found the right so far.

After installation of the apache2 for Gerrit (by [this](https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/07/28/ubuntu-16-04-gerrit-and-jenkins-for-code-review/#sec-1-3) guide) I haven't touched the apache2.conf, I just added a gerrit.conf in the mods-enable subfolder of apache2 with this content:

```
ProxyPass           /gerrit  http://localhost:8081/gerrit nocanon
ProxyPassReverse    /gerrit  http://localhost:8081/gerrit nocanon
ProxyRequests       Off

<Proxy http://localhost:8081/gerrit>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /gerrit>
  AuthType Digest
  AuthName "gerrit"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htdigest
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When I access Gerrit using our address/gerrit I get asked for the permission which we added using htdigest in the first place.

Any Idea what's wrong? Why Gitblit is ask for a log-in and doesn't accept any?
(I'm new in Apache authentication at all)

Answer (score 0):

http://gitblit.com/setup_authentication.html
Gitblit only support authtype below:

```
LDAP authentication
Windows authentication
PAM authentication
Htpasswd authentication
HTTP header authentication
Redmine auhentication
Salesforce.com authentication
Servlet container authentication
```

But your auth type is Digest, you can try switching auth type to htpasswd by the below steps:

1. add a new auth file
   sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd log_name_xxx
2. modify your gerrit.conf in /etc/apache2/...

   AuthType Basic
     AuthName "gerrit"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
3. restart apache2

   sudo service apache2 restart

Please let me know if there is any other problem.
Hope it useful. Ahhhhh